# Loop part of a tween with tween.js

Tags: javascript, createjs

Here's a simple tween in Tween.js. A simple loop happens after an interval.

```
cjs.Tween.get(mySymbol).wait(50).to({x:10}).to({x:0});
```

Is there a way to make it repeat say 5 times after the interval, without repeating the interval?

By adding `loop:true` I can make it loop but the loop would include the wait().

```
cjs.Tween.get(mySymbol, {loop:true}).wait(50).to({x:10}).to({x:0});
```

Is there any way to add tweens to the timeline sequentially in Tween.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Answer](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/tweenjs/7-timeline) courtesy of Grant Skinner:

```
cjs.Tween.get(ball).wait(1000).play(
    cjs.Tween.get(ball,{paused:true, loop:true})
    .to({x:450},1000)
    .to({x:50},1000)
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

To loop 5 times you can use a callback:

```
var tl = new createjs.Timeline();

tl.addTween(createjs.Tween.get(mySymbol).wait(500).call(loop, [mySymbol, 0], this));

var i;
var loopMax = 5;

function loop(target, initI){

    if (initI != null) {
        i = initI;
    } else {
        i++
    }

    if (i < loopMax) createjs.Tween.get(target).to({x:450},1000).to({x:50},1000).call(loop, [target]);

}
```